No autocomplete for iostream and vector header files in nvim (clang LSP)
Basically im on Linux (arch btw) and i want to make a Windows programs
I installed mingw and specified the include paths but I'm getting errors in the LSP with iostream and vector (in this case didn't tried other libraries )
This is the compile_flags.txt file for adding the include paths:
--target=x86_64-w64-mingw32
-I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/
-I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/14.2.0
-D_WIN32
-D_WINDOWS
-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

This is the problem
Warnings and errors
I have no autocomplete for those headers and I'm getting errors. Everything compiles and works but the thing that piss me off is the autocomplete and the errors, i just don't understand.
The include paths are correct, i checked it 10000 times.
If you also need my lspconfig here it is:
return {
  {
    "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
    config = function()
      require("lspconfig").clangd.setup({
        capabilities = {
          offsetEncoding = { "utf-8", "utf-16" },
          textDocument = {
            completion = {
              editsNearCursor = true,
            },
          },
        },
        cmd = { "clangd" },
        filetypes = { "c", "cpp", "objc", "objcpp", "cuda", "proto" },
      })
      require("lspconfig").pyright.setup({
        cmd = { "pyright-langserver", "--stdio" },
        filetypes = { "python" },
        settings = {
          python = {
            analysis = {
              autoSearchPaths = true,
              diagnosticMode = "openFilesOnly",
              useLibraryCodeForTypes = true,
            },
          },
        },
        single_file_support = true,
      })
    end,
  },
}



Ok, I don't know if i need to remove this question because, today, with a refreshed mindset, i realised that the name of the file i was editing was: "filename.c" instead of "filename.cpp" for C++ coding. That was the problem
